# Program crashes when i change the initialization value of an int data member to anything other than 1

Tags: c++, design-patterns, initialization

Earlier i moved some data to a singleton object, GamePropertiesManager. In this class i define a variable called _gameSpeed and in the class constructor i use an intialisation list to set it to 1 as default.

In another class i have an update loop that, (outside of my control), will always update as frequently as possible. I intended to, and successfully used a 'speed' variable to slow down the updating. This worked by, say, setting it to 2 the game would only update every other call to onUpdate.. I might make sense if you look at the contents of PlayState::onUpdate() below (I posted the whole cpp under the advice of a commenter):

```
#include "PlayState.hpp"
#include "PlayerController.hpp"
#include "AIController.hpp"

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

//testin
#include <iostream>

/// Implement PlayState

PlayState::PlayState()
{}
PlayState::~PlayState()
{}

bool PlayState::onCreate()
{
   _gameProperties = GamePropertiesManager::GetInstance();

   _frameCounter = 0;
   application.addKeyListener( *this );
   _collisionFlag = false;

   //snakes created, intialising a pointer to fruit managaer, controller and opposing snake
   _player1 = new Snake();
   _player2 = new Snake();
   _player1->Initialise(&_fruitManager, new PlayerController(_player1), _player2);
   _player2->Initialise(&_fruitManager, new AIController(_player2), _player1);

   return true;
}
bool PlayState::onDestroy()
{
   return true;
}

void PlayState::onEntry()
{
   //seed to randomise food positions later
    srand ( time(0) );
}

void PlayState::onExit()
{

}

void PlayState::onUpdate()
{
   //TODO: rename _snake speed and maybe make it global gamespeed
   ++_frameCounter; //FrameCounter can be used to slow the snake down
   if(_frameCounter >= _gameProperties->GetGameSpeed())
   {

       //updating
       _fruitManager.UpdateFruits();
      _player1->Update(&_collisionFlag);
      _player2->Update(&_collisionFlag);

      if (_collisionFlag)
         application.setState("gameover");

      _frameCounter = 0;
   }

}

void PlayState::onRender( Canvas& c )
{
   _player1->Draw(c);
   _player2->Draw(c);

    _fruitManager.DrawFruits(c);
}

bool PlayState::onKey (const KeyEvent& key)
{
if( key.key_state == KeyEvent::KB_DOWN ){

    switch (key.key){
         case KeyEvent::KB_ESC_KEY:
            application.exit();
            break;
        case 'p':
            application.setState("pause");
            break;
      }
}
   return true;
}
```

_gameProperties is a pointer to a/the GamePropertiesManager which i assign in PlayState::onCreate(), when my class PlayState is first created..

The actual GamePropertiesManager class looks like this:

```
#include "GamePropertiesManager.hpp"

GamePropertiesManager* GamePropertiesManager::_instance = NULL;

GamePropertiesManager* GamePropertiesManager::GetInstance()
{
   if (!_instance) //instance not yet created
      _instance = new GamePropertiesManager();

   return _instance;
}

void GamePropertiesManager::Destroy()
{
   delete _instance;
   _instance = 0;
}

GamePropertiesManager::GamePropertiesManager() :
   _gameMode(PLAYERVSCOM), _player1Name("Player 1"), _player2Name("Player 2"),
      _player1Score(0), _player2Score(0), _matchSurvivor("NONE"), _gameSpeed(1)
{

}

unsigned int GamePropertiesManager::GetGameSpeed()
{
   return _gameSpeed;
}
```

**My problem is that, when i change the value of _gameSpeed in the initialisation list to any value aside from (1) my program crashes at runtime.** I find this particularly odd as i was previously comparing _frameCounter to both hard coded values other than 1 and a speed variable set to values other than 1 and the program ran fine as expected. Any ideas about the problem?

Hope i explained myself well enough, appreciate your help!

Comment: Going to have to show more code if you want assistance.

Comment: @SamDeHaan okay thanks, i'm afraid i may just have cluttered things up more, i think i had already posted all the relevant info, but under your advice i've added the PlayState in it's entirety, hopefully the additional context will help :)

Comment: I wonder what books/sites continually recommend leading `_` when so much of the time they're illegal.

Comment: `_fruitManager.UpdateFruits()` may initialize something. Without the first call to it in the first onUpdate(), it breaks?

Comment: @MarkB Yeah i'm not sure why so many books and teachers have told me it's fine to use leading underscores for member variables. for now i'm trying to stay consistant but i will do away with this approach in all future projects i work on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is almost certainly because for any value other than 1, in the first call to `PlayState::onUpdate` the `if` check won't run, most likely leaving something uninitialized.

Comment: Thanks for the observation upon further investigation you were absolutely correct. My "solution" was to just initialise  the _frameCounter = to the game speed and then increment it after the if condition to ensure that it would always enter that condition on the first call.. Probably should have rethought my architecture but this is my first major project and i'm just trying to make progress :p

Answer (score 1):

If your process is multithreaded, with multiple threads making it to `onUpdate`, then you need to add adequate locking to `GetInstance`, to make sure that two competing threads cannot create independent instances upon the first (concurrent) invocations, and more importantly, to have one thread publish an incompletely initialized instance started by another thread.

Comment: @Holly - I will expand the answer if you confirm multithreading.